# AS3 input text goto frame for noob like me

Tags: actionscript-3, text, input, frame, goto

Can someone pls help me on this. I had accident recently and forgot all of this. Now i want to work again on it...So..Thing is. I want some text field with submit button. When i input in text field certain number and clcik submit, then it takes me to corresponded frame when all the data regarding that number in input box will be. For example, i need to put number 100, and i dedicated frame 100 to that input, so user clcik submit and takes him to frame 100.
Thank you very much
I did find something like this

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
submitbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testPassword); 

function testPassword(e:MouseEvent):void { 
if (numbertext.text == "903") { 
     gotoAndPlay(903);
} else { 
     gotoAndPlay(200);
  }
  }
```

Something like that

Comment: And the **problem** is what? I don't see a programming question. Try something and then ask here when you have an error message or a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My solution:

Pass number, not string to Number DataType.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
import flash.display.MovieClip

var numbertext:Number = 0;
var MyClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

submitbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testPassword); 

function testPassword(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    if (numbertext == 903) { 
         MyClip.gotoAndPlay(903);
    } 
    else { 
        MyClip.gotoAndPlay(200);
    }
}
```

Note if you add it to the frame use `this.gotoAnPlay(number)`

To learn more about `gotoAndPlay()` visit [ActionScript gotoAndPlay](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html)

Comment: Oops I've clicked upvote. Check _"When i **input in text field** certain number"_ to understand why `String` is used.

Comment: Thanks for Upvote!  Now I understand why `String` is used.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder Thank you, but in this case it allways go to frame 200, no matter what number i wrote in. Even if i put right number 903, it gors to frame 200, not 903.  How can i fix that? When i change numbertext, nothing happened, allways wrong and go to 200, when i put numbertext 0, then allways go to 903 no matter what i wrote. i dont understand...

Comment: @KŠiljo I updated the code, you have to attach a movieClip or Frame.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder  i did add textbox and button as movieclip on frame. Keep in mind i want to set whole set of parameters and frames here. So i want code to edit as i write it for each frame. So when someone puts 700, it drives him to frame 500 where dana for 700 input is, when it puts 800 it drives him to some other lets say 550, when inputs somthing unrecognized it drives him on First frame. etc.

Comment: MAybe it should be gotoAndStop  order...im really lost

Comment: Sorry you are getting lost. I will suggest that you read gotoAndPlay API.  If you explain better what you are trying to achieve, I may be able to code it for you,  To learn more about gotoAndPlay,  I added a link in my edited answer.

Comment: Yes im all lost in this scripting cause this isnt my field at all. Im just tryi g to figure out this one thing for my project...and im too old and lazy to learn some coding from scratch. But ok...ill figure out something.  Thanks all of you for helping specialy you @LasVegasCoder

Comment: So let me explain better. Im reallytrying hard but i did stuck somewhere. So i made app for android in flash. And i need one frame with textbox...and submit button. Then when people input max 3 number digits in that box and click submit...that will take them to related frame. So for example...i input 708...it takes me to frame 708 and i read what i need from there. Etc. Im working on CS6 AS3 AIR 3.2. so thats all. I did try different scripts and combinations and im really tryng...but eaither im stupid or i cant figure out obvious. Remember i have no knowledge of programing whatsoever.

Comment: But...when i stuck to something i somehow find sokutions etc...in this case i dont know what to look and how to sort it. Unfortunately. Thank you all once again.

Comment: You are welcome, I read your summary of what you want, I will try and code  one and explain it line by line.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder i would love that...with explanations...i need to learn some stuff...i hope ill get it for sure...thanx

Comment: @LasVegasCoder Any News? I still cant figure it  out...thanx

Comment: @KŠiljo I will post you full codes here today, I was busy not on here, just got back.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder i did make this done, but only with code i firsrt wrote. And it Works but only for one input. And i need much more inputs i will then sort out, maybe 100 of them...So i did aomething like this          import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
submitbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testPassword); 

function testPassword(e:MouseEvent):void { 
if (numbertext.text == "102") { 
     gotoAndStop(102);
 } 
  if (numbertext.text == "103")  {
     gotoAndStop(103);
} else { 
     gotoAndStop(101);
  }

  }

Comment: Now i get this error: "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/testPassword()[Untitled_fla.MainTimeline::frame200:24]"

Comment: @LasVegasCoder i got it my friend, else if is the command i was looking for, well now i did figure it ut somthing. Thank ou very much. But, if u still want pls send me all explanations for above code to my mail mr.shiljo@gmail.com because i want to understand better. Beer is on me...who knows maybe

Comment: I'm glad to  be of help.  I will send you some codes as well. If my answer has helped you, mark it as Accepted answer to help others.  Thank you